# Подсветка python-синтаксиса в notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++

Для написания python-скриптов "на скорую руку" я использую Notepad++ (вместо создания проекта в pyCharm), но мне не нравится ни один из стандартных стилей подсветки синтаксиса. Такое ощущение, что у меня одного такая проблема. Хотелось бы узнать, может быть, есть какой-то интернет-ресурс, куда люди выкладывают свои собственные синтаксисы, откуда можно просто скачать конфиг-файл?
Очень не хочется тратить кучу времени на создание собственного конфига

Comment: возможно, Вам нужно ещё и темой поиграться? по "notepad++ themes" находится десятки сайтов с красивыми темами.

Comment: может быть и есть какой-то ресурс. У гугла спрашивал уже?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел тему здесь [npp dracula](https://github.com/gogo2/npp-darcula)

Один в один как в pyCharm

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).